# AWS Lambda - NodeJS based function that requires Linux dependency packages

Tags: c++, node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to create a function which is based on NodeJS that runs a C++ compiled code. The C++ code required  me to install certain Linux packages using 'yum' in order to run.

The NodeJS and the C++ parts work great when running on Docker, because in the DockerFile I can install all the needed Linux dependencies that the C++ code requires using 'yum' command before the app execution.

When running under a Lambda I do not know how to tell the running container to install these Linux packages in order the C++ to run and be loaded successfully by the NodeJS.

I am trying to create a NodeJS Runtime based function with all my code and add a Custom Runtime layer before the function loads that can install all the dependencies to the OS (Not NodeJS dependencies - Linux OS dependencies).
I tried creating a custom runtime function but didn't understand how to connect everything and how it should (if possible) connect to the function itself even after configuring the layer version to the function.

Does anyone know how such a thing can be achieved?

Comment: "I read that" - where did you read? Any link? You can't modify lambda runtime environment like you can with your own container, which includes installing any packages on it. Your app must be self-sufficient, and contain all dependencies in itself, or through layers.

Comment: @Marcin I fixed the question. I read a lot of articles and the AWS documentation, I just couldn't find what I am asking for, that is what I meant.
I understand it must be self sufficient. I must provide all dependencies on the ZIP file provided.
This is, as I understand, the purpose of creating a Custom Runtime Function.
Is it possible to create a layer that has Custom Runtime and the function itself is NodeJS based?